# Need to replace use of strcpy_s in C code used in iPhone project

Tags: iphone, c, visual-studio

I have a C SDK I need to use in an iPhone project, and the example code was written for use with Visual Studio. It includes use of strcpy_s, which is a Microsoft-only string function.

```
file_header.header_size = FIT_FILE_HDR_SIZE;
strcpy_s((FIT_UINT8 *)&file_header.data_type, sizeof(".FIT"), ".FIT");  << problem!
```

I've tried changing to strcpy and strncpy like so

```
strncpy((FIT_UINT8 *)&file_header.data_type, ".FIT", sizeof(".FIT"));
```

But I get this warning:

warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of '**builtin**_strncpy_chk' differ in signedness

warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of '__inline_strncpy_chk' differ in signedness

warning: call to **builtin**_strncpy_chk will always overflow destination buffer

The struct file_header is this:

```
typedef struct
{
   FIT_UINT8 header_size; // FIT_FILE_HDR_SIZE (size of this structure)
   FIT_UINT8 protocol_version; // FIT_PROTOCOL_VERSION
   FIT_UINT16 profile_version; // FIT_PROFILE_VERSION
   FIT_UINT32 data_size; // Does not include file header or crc.  Little endian format.
   FIT_UINT8 data_type[4]; // ".FIT"
} FIT_FILE_HDR;
```

FIT_UINT8 is typedef Unsigned char.

So we can see that it is given an length of 4 in the typedef, and the strcpy_s takes the data_type by reference and copys ".FIT" to it.  Where am I going wrong with strncpy?  If you haven't guessed by now I'm not much of a C programmer :)

Edit: this does not give me an error, but it is correct?

```
strncpy((void *)&file_header.data_type, ".FIT", sizeof(file_header.data_type));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any "safe string" operations, the size should almost always be the size of the **destination** buffer; if you use the size of the source string, you might as well call `memcpy`.

If you want C99 conformance:

```
strncpy(file_header.data_type, ".FIT", sizeof file_header.data_type);
```

However, `strlcpy` (a BSDism, available in iOS) is preferred by many, because it guarantees that the destination will be nul-terminated:

```
strlcpy(file_header.data_type, ".FIT", sizeof file_header.data_type);
```

Note, however that the nul-terminated string ".FIT" doesn't actually fit in the allotted space, as it requires 5 characters (1 for the trailing nul).  If you use `strlcpy`, you will see that the resulting string is just ".FI" because `strlcpy` guarantees nul-termination, and truncates your string if necessary.

If you require nul-termination then, you probably want to increase the size of the `data_type` array to 5.  As **caf** correctly points out, this looks like a file header, in which case nul-termination is probably not required; in that case `strncpy` is preferred; I might even use `memcpy`, and avoid giving a future developer the idea that the field is a string.

Comment: Since this string is apparently stored in a fixed-size field in a file header, nul-termination is probably *not* required, and it might actually be one of the few occaisions when `strncpy()` is exactly what is called for.  Somewhat ironically, the `strcpy_s()` version seems to have been overflowing the destination buffer!

Comment: @caf: just as long as you don't ever try to use the field as a normal C string, and clearly document that you can't do so.

Comment: I have found memcpy to be a good alternative when using fixed-width arrays of chars (I hesitate to use "string" in this context.)  Fixed-width strings fit memcpy's intended use, and the appearance of the function (rather than str*cpy),  serves as an reminder that the operand is not a plain old NULL-terminated C-string.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use

```
sizeof(".FIT")
```

use

```
strlen(".FIT")
```

Comment: To nit-pick, sizeof() is fine here (admittedly, it could lead to some bad habits)